# Is there a good tool to backup the data from all my webapp accounts to my computer?

Tags: webapp-rec, backup, download, export

Traditionally, you backup your computer's data to the web, but anyone who uses a lot of webapps puts a lot of data out there. Is there a good tool to backup all my gmail mail, facebook pictures and status updates, google docs, etc. to my computer? Preferably automatically.

Comment: I don't think there is a "one-tool-takes-them-all" solution. It would be much better to ask a question specific to a single service. I've seen already some questions for this type of tools. Eventually you should make this a "list"-style community wiki question.

Answer (score 10):

[Backupify](http://www.backupify.com/) does do all of the items you listed in your post: gmail, facebook, google docs, etc. and a bunch more as well.

Answer (score 2):

I actually work for Backupify and yes, we would be a great solution to your problem. If interested, we have a free for life account that you can try, and upgrade from there if need be. Let me know if you have any questions.

Click [here](https://secure.backupify.com/signup) if you want to signup